# using multiple commas in a sentence

Tags: grammar, commas, articles

I wrote this sentence in a letter, but I am not confident about the use of multiple commas. The sentence probably lacks proper use of articles as well.

> “Due to the halved frequency of this route, passengers like myself, who catch train in the afternoon, have to wait double the time to get on a bus.”

Apologies for asking two questions (use of commas, and articles) in one post.

Edit: I didn’t realise I should have added a task / question prompt to help everyone understand the background.

I was practicing writing a formal letter, and subject was to “write a letter to the manager of your local bus service. They have recently made some changes to the service which created inconvenience for you.”

In first paragraph, I wrote that a bus service between a primary school and the train station has been reduced for non-peak hours, and in second paragraph I wanted to say “Due to the halved frequency of the bus service to the train station, commuters who have to go to the train station using bus, have to wait double the time to catch the bus”

Comment: What's the question? Please also include what you've checked so far, and why it hasn't helped.

Comment: It's difficult to find recommendations on the exact comma usage one needs advice on. Your sentence isn't totally clear, but I'd suggest 'Because of the halved frequency on this route, passengers like myself, who previously caught the train in the afternoon, now have to wait double the time to catch a bus.' I've retained all the commas as I believe that improved readability outweighs the benefits of decluttering here. I've also made minor changes; I've chosen 'because of' not because 'due to' is incorrect there, but because I get fed up of arguing with people who believe it is.

Comment: ***All*** of those commas are optional stylistic choices, since it's perfectly possible to ***say*** the cited utterance without any significant pauses.

Comment: Apologies for incomplete post, I have updated the question. Edwin, that’s a great concept you pointed out and that was something I wasn’t entirely sure about- commas could be added to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence was perfectly understandable to me after I included the article *the* in front of *train*.

Your commas were placed correctly:  Your introductory phrase **requires** a comma after it, and the modifying phrase, *who catch the train in the afternoon*, requires commas around it.  @Edwin Ashworth's sentence puts your thoughts into a more formal style (and possibly changes the meaning as well, since I took your sentence to mean you catch the train first and then have to wait double the time for the bus).  However, other than the *the*, your sentence is fine and no one should find fault in it.

You sound like you may be learning English.  You may be interested to know there is an entire StackExchange community for English Language Learners.  Here it is: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hello, Ginny. If you're going to submit an 'answer', you're expected to give linked and attributed supporting references. // I'd say that  'Because of cuts, passengers like myself who used to catch the train now have to wait double the time to get  a bus.' is totally acceptable. There's a move towards decluttering / minimal punctuation, and 'who used to catch the train' is arguably restrictive.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin.  I'll do better next time!

Comment: @GinnyBethoc Thanks for your input. And I actually meant “ to catch the train (to reach the train station by the bus), passengers have to wait double the time to catch the bus (again, to reach the train station). Also, thank you for sharing a link to stack exchange community. I’ve been using english for a while, but I’m sure there are many things that I need to correct / improve:) EdwinAshworth - thanks for your suggestion, that helps :)